# What documents/procedures I have to follow to fly my aircraft from the UK to Norway?

Tags: general-aviation, flight-planning, uk, norway

I'm planning a trip to Norway for when Covid restrictions here in the UK are lifted, and was wondering what documentation is needed to enter Norway. I've already emailed AVINOR, and they simply gave me a link to toll.no, which yields no helpful information.

I'll be flying myself in a British aircraft. I'll be departing from Wick in Scotland and arriving in Kristiansand Kjevik in Norway. I'd like the details as if it were normal, pre-covid times.

Comment: This is fundamentally unknowable. Restrictions around the world have changed abruptly, sometimes with only hours notice. We don't know when the UK will lift restrictions to allow this sort of flight, and we don't know what changes the Norwegians will make in the mean time.

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan I'm wanting to know the information as if it were normal pre-covid times.

Comment: I checked the AIP, AIP SUP, and AIC, and nothing stands out. But covid is not really avinor's area, see for example: https://www.visitnorway.com/plan-your-trip/coronavirus-and-travelling-to-norway/ -- if you need more info on things like *that,* i.e. not AIP related, I recommend Stack Exchange's Travel site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to contact the [Kristiansand customs office](https://www.toll.no/en/about-norwegian-customs/contact-us/customs-offices/all-customs-offices/kristiansand/) and ask them that question. They are likely to be the most direct source for the answers you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Are you flying in your own plane, or as a passenger on an airline?  https://www.udi.no/en/want-to-apply/visit-and-holiday/?resetguide=1 will give you some info, but not everything you need if you're flying in yourself.

Comment: Considering the "cessna-172" tag, I'd go with option A

Comment: I'm flying in myself.